# CSS Font-face doesn't work on IE8, but works on IE9

Tags: css, font-face

I have one font working fine in both IE8 and IE9 and all other browsers, but the second one only works in IE9 and the other browsers.  In IE8, I get the error:

"CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error."

I have been reading around and tried a number of things with no luck.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Site</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css"> 
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Cake";
        src: url('cake.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */ 
        src: url('cake.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ 
             url('cake.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ 
             url('cake.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ 
             url('cake.svg#svgCake') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */ 
    }
    p {
        font-family: "Cake";
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Testing font</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried regenerating the eot with a few different generators and multiple times, playing around with the CSS, playing with headers, playing with domains, etc, but it appears that they are all fine.  As mentioned, the same code on the same, just pointing to different font files work fine.  For some reason this one file doesn't want to work.  I looked at the ttfpatch program, but it tells me that the tableversion of the font is 3, which is the same as the other working font.  These fonts were modified by a program called Type Light 3.2 to add a few French characters, but as mentioned works on all other browsers.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT:

One thing I realized is that the EOT file is not being read by IE9, it is giving the same error, just using the WOFF file.  You can download the original font at http://www.searchfreefonts.com/free/cake.htm.  Can anyone get that working in IE8?

EDIT 2:

Looking in the developer tools, the eot fonts appear to be downloading and are the correct type.  I get a 304 response code back.

Comment: You mentioned trying different generators but did you remember to clear your cache each time?

Comment: I used the IE developers tools clear cache, but I have had problems with that not working in the past, so you could be on to something.

Comment: One thing to be aware of, due to the proprietary crappiness of the EOT format it's my understanding that there's actually only one tool (WEFT from MS) that makes them. I suspect practically all online services are actually using the same backend tool. It's possible the Type Light edits are incompatible with it.

Comment: Thanks Spliff.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.  I tried changing the filename as well to make sure its not a cache issue.  Even tried the original file before we modified and same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution for this.  Redownloaded and regenerated the font numerous times on different computers, clearing cache each time viewed and still didn't work.  Other fonts work fine, so my conclusion is the eot generators don't like the font.

Comment: did you try the eot file generated by http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [font-face](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) generator.

Comment: Did you alter with the .htaccess file??

Comment: Alter what, the headers?  I played around with that, but it doesn't make sense to be that if one file works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/ as it worked many times for our users.